# Working with Security and Sessions, is this secure enough?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

There is only ever going to be 1 username and 1 password to access this page, so decided to store it within PHP itself, as it probably is more secure than storing it within the database.  However, I'm trying to get a grip on sessions and hoping that:

1. It will not compromise security in any way.
2. It will not stop the session (for logged in user(s)) scripts from running when other people try to log in and fail.  For example, I don't want it to delete the session for the logged in user.  Probably a stupid question, but figured I'd ask anyways.

My `index.php` file for this, in php looks like this:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['Admin']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) && $_POST['username'] == 'someUsername' && $_POST['password'] == 'someVeryStrongPassword')
    {
        $_SESSION['Admin'] = true;
        session_write_close();
    }
    else {
            // You don't have access, go back to login page.
        session_destroy();
        header("location:login.php");
        exit();
    }
}

// This will now be used for any subsequent, same page requests, such as:  `index.php?action={something}`, etc. but will always use `index.php` as the main page.

// Is it now safe to continue on with code assuming that the user is logged in at this point?  Should there be anything else to consider adding?  Possibly into the $_SESSION[] array?
```

My login.php file is just HTML really and looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Administration</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="login" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <label for="user">Username: <input id="user" type="text" name="username" /></label><br />
    <label for="pass">Password: <input id="pass" type="password" name="password" /></label><br />
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, I am planning on attaching the `$sess_id` variable to all forms that get submitted within the `index.php` file and checking it against `session_id()`.  Is this secure enough?  Been looking at [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) and [session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php).  People have reported that `session_regenerate_id` causes problems when multiple users are logged in (old session id vs. new session ids).  Would it be wise to use `session_regenerate_id` at all, in my situation (since I'm not storing any data into the database)?

Updated code thanks to `M Miller`

Comment: You should store a hash of the password.

Comment: Multiple users sharing a single login is always BAD BAD BAD. How do you identify which user made a change? How do you remove access from only one of the uers?

Comment: @Fluffeh - Ok, thanks, not a problem, only 1 user will have access in that case!  Thanks

Comment: @SLaks - Store a hash of the password?  Why is that important if the password is Server-side stored already?

Comment: Just a note, you're calling `session_start()` twice, and you should probably call `exit;` after your `header('Location: login.php');` (I think a browser can deny a header... am I crazy?).

Comment: Ok, so ha, I don't need a `session_start` after the `if` statement proves they logged in correctly.  Thanks, I kinda thought I needed it again.  And Ok, will add `exit();` awesome Thank you!

Comment: @SolomonClosson: So that someone who can read your source won't be able to log in.

Comment: I'd assume that if somebody can *read* the source, they can modify at as well (e.g. change `if (loggedIn())` to `if (true)`). But of course, if you're going to use the same password as you do for your personal bank account, by all means, hash the heck out of it. And don't run this on a server without SSL either.

Comment: How will they be able to ready my source code?  Are there PHP Source code readers out there?  Really?  And OK, if you think it will help!  Definitely will do.  Should I do the same with the `Username` also?

Comment: @SolomonClosson, they'd need access to your web server to read the PHP source. But I did confirm what I said earlier, add `exit` definitely, because a browser can deny a Location redirect and load whatever HTML/execute whatever PHP follows it.

Comment: @MMiller - Thanks a million for confirming this!  Really useful to know this!

Comment: Hashing the password does not make sense if it is stored in the source file.

Comment: I think that you should not use the `session_regenerate_id` function, nor should you append the session ID to the URL. Adding the ID to the URL is insecure because if somebody reads the browser history, they have access to a previous session ID -- and if you use `session_regenerate_id`, as you said, it creates conflict if multiple users are logged in simultaneously. Instead, you should give the session an inactivity timeout, e.g. at every PHP request, do `if ($_SESSION['to'] < time()) { /* logout */ } $_SESSION['to'] = time()+3600;`.

Comment: Wow, this is great.  Exactly what I am asking for!  Can you put that in the form of an answer?

Comment: When all is said and done, HTTP Authentication is the safest, although not always the most UX-friendly. http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/12/30/saving_http_authentication/

Comment: Sure, hold on. Let me gather my thoughts.

Comment: lol, you're the BEST!  And that means that I have to store the time() within `$_SESSION['to']` right?  Can you provide an example of that as well, within my code?

Comment: @MMiller - Updated code with your suggestions, hopefully I updated it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I kind of learned this wrong initially. I always thought that PHP sessions were something unique and secure intrinsically. But sessions are just cookies that terminate at the end of the browser session. PHP sessions are more intelligently crafted than your average cookie, but they've got most of the same vulnerabilities and flaws. Cookies just plain aren't safe.

First of all, you should set `session.use_only_cookies`. Oftentimes it's easier to get an HTTP request than it is to get cookies from an unsuspecting victim. History is easier to read, and people often clear cookies without clearing history. It's also displayed on your freaking monitor, so you might as well have your URL be http://example.com/admin/index.php?username=admin&password=MyPaSsWoRd!123

You have two possible courses of action: if you use `session_regenerate_id(true)`, you'll need to implement a system for multiple simultaneous logons -- or you can just assume that if somebody logs in from another device, everybody else's access will terminate.

I prefer an inactivity timeout, because a session lasts as long as the browser is open -- and who knows how long that will be?

You just need this logic:

On login:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['Admin'] = true;
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time()+3600; // +1 hour
?>
```

And on subsequent admin pages:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['timeout']) || $_SESSION['timeout'] < time()) {
   // destroy the session
   // redirect to login
   exit;
}
?>
```

(If you're developing a UI, maybe you want to add a warning when the timeout approaches so that the user doesn't lose his information.)

Don't worry about putting everything on `index.php`, because none of that matters.

Don't rely on things like the client's OS, browser, or IP address. These are unreliable, subject to change, and can be easily spoofed. Although the IP address can't be faked (technically, not to any use), your IP address might change during the session and you could lock yourself out.

To be honest, if you're going to have multiple sign-ins from different devices at the same time, I'd avoid regenerating the session ID. If you're the only user, then use it, because it does sort of add a layer of security. The scenario is, if a session ID is obtained, the hacker only has a short window of opportunity to use the session before it is regenerated by you, the user.

Charles Miller wrote a great article about persistent authentication, and this is where I'll point you to, because this is how I learned how to do my auth: http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/ (Disregard the Barry Jaspan link at the bottom, it's not really any more secure, and it's needlessly more complicated.) `session_regenerate_id` would make implementing this system pretty easy -- and it'd be very simple if you only had one user. In fact, you could store a history of session IDs and, assuming that no session ID will ever be reused in the foreseeable future of your app (and it's highly unlikely), you could simply say that if someone tries to access your app using a previously used and now invalidated session ID, you can assume they're a hacker and act accordingly.

Here's a way to implement just that (using no database, for simplicity's sake):

```
<?php
$sessions = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('sessions.log'));
   // Get the history of all past sessions
if (in_array(session_id(), $sessions) {
   // The current session ID is a session that has already been discarded
   // Hijack alert!
   mail('youremail@example.com', 'HIJACK ALERT!', 'Somebody tried to use the session '.session_id().'! The bastard\'s IP was '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'From: php@server');
   session_destroy();
   echo 'Nice try, jerk! The admin has been notified....';
   exit;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['Admin']) && $_SESSION['Admin']) {
   // Logged in!
   file_put_contents('sessions.log', PHP_EOL.session_id(), FILE_APPEND);
      // Add the current session ID to a file containing a history of session IDs
   session_regenerate_id(true);
      // Regenerate the session and delete the old one
}
?>
```

(Untested.) Granted, this is a rather primitive example, but it might be what you need.

The *best* solution is, as I mentioned in the comments, HTTP authentication, so use that if it's an option.

And the last thing we talked about: hashing the password. If somebody gains access to your file server and consequently your source code, you're in trouble and your application is compromised regardless. But if you use the same password elsewhere, by all means, only store a hash of it in the source code so you can limit the damage. Then, if your password is the same as your bank account's password, at least the hacker only sees

```
if (hash('whirlpool', $_POST['password'].$salt) == '9923afaec3a86f865bb231a588f453f84e8151a2deb4109aebc6de4284be5bebcff4fab82a7e51d920237340a043736e9d13bab196006dcca0fe65314d68eab9')
```

(P.S. Whirlpool is the best hash, in my opinion. And my favorite way to salt is to split the password in half and stick the salt in the middle. Then, even if both are known and the hacker has a super hash table, he's still screwed. e.g. `$half = floor(strlen($password)/2); $hash = hash('whirlpool', substr($password, 0, $half).$salt.substr($password, $half));`)

Comment: Oh, also, that `sessions.log` in the Charles Miller example would get VERY big VERY fast. It'd be better to use a MySQL table and purge old sessions periodically, because a hacker isn't going to use a session_id that was sent 2 weeks ago, and if he does, worst case is he can't log in, but you don't get an e-mail. And a hacker who's THAT stupid isn't really threatening enough to warrant an e-mail.

Comment: thinking of using the 1 hour timeout approach.  Should I still use `session.use_only_cookies`?  I don't really want to allow anymore than 1 user logged in at one time now, as I can see that allowing more users will be much more complicated... and just trying to make something simple and secure!

Comment: Yes, you should set `use_only_cookies` in your configuration anyways. It's good practice. It's a choice of allowing users the convenience of disabling cookies (which no rational user would do) at the cost of making it less secure for everybody else on your server. Avoid it. By the way, I know it was a lot to digest, so I put a script on Pastebin. Untested, but at least it shows the flow: http://pastebin.com/2QSdwvLP

Comment: Wow, that's great, but I don't see you using `ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);` anywhere in that pastebin example, unless it isn't needed for that... Also, what are you using to generate `HASHED_PASSWORD`, am now thinking of using your approach in that pastebin example... seems even better than mine.  Also, in your example, are you using `ADMIN_EMAIL` for the username?

Comment: Thanks for the details, I want to use your example, but not exactly sure how to use it in my code... thanks anyways, suppose I'll just use the hour and session.use_only_cookies.

Comment: I was using 'username' for the username (line 29). I should've made a constant for that. Also, I prefer to change the PHP configuration over `ini_set`, if possible, which is why it wasn't in my example. As for the HASHED_PASSWORD, I simply did as the formula works: I took the word `password` and stuck the salt in the middle, i.e. `pass;jfakw8io93390a';f.cvx,nz.,word`. Then I converted it to a Whirlpool hash: http://hash.online-convert.com/whirlpool-generator

Comment: Here's a complete, working example (I had a lot to rearrange and debug). I'll be using a variation of this myself for my next Persistent Auth site. https://copy.com/qmI7nIEXAVtZlKbk

Comment: Wow, thanks, on my way home from work, so will take a look at it soon!  Many Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use only sessions there will be always a possibility that the session gets hijacked. Sessions are good but you need more protection to make it harder to get in. for example you could...

1)check if the IP address of the client changes during the session (this makes session hijacking a pain in the ass)

2)use some cookies to identify the client

Comment: Well, being that 1. This will always call `index.php?action=someaction` and never fall outside of the `index.php` call, and 2. for added security, adding `$sess_id to form action urls that are submitting to `index.php?action=something`, does this mean that I don't need to worry about this since `$_SESSION['Admin']` within the top few lines of my php code should take care of this automatically for me, correct??

Comment: If the user has a dynamic IP address or uses multiple devices simultaneously, you have problems.

Comment: Ok, great, I'm glad I asked this question before I went down the `session_id` route!!

Comment: yes, you don't need to append the session id to the form action urls. In fact it is better not to do it because it makes it easy to steal the session id which is obviously not good.

Comment: however, now I think about it... you could always append a salted hash from the session id, server time, ip adress. Or even better write the hash in a cookie. You could go as far as you want but in the end you'll always be hackable. So keep in mind how important/sensitive the data is you want to protect and integrate appropriate/matched protection.

Comment: Well, if the hash will be hackable, than I'd rather not use it.  Unless people can hack the `$_SESSION['Admin']` than I'd rather stick with that instead!